# Horizontal scroll in Stack Overflow App on Android

Tags: bug, android-app, user-experience, stack-overflow-app

I am experiencing poor UX using the Stack Overflow Android application.

Horizontal scrolling collides with vertical exactly on code snippets.

I have recorded a video that demonstrates this strange behavior:
https://youtu.be/GZheZseoc20 <sub>(I am not able to attach a GIF image here because it has size ~8 MB)</sub>

Environment:

- Device: Meizu M3s
- OS: Android 5.1
- Build number: Flyme 6.1.0.0G

Comment: I have also encountered this (and been frustrated by it).  One of the things that makes me not want to use the Android app, unfortunately.